# Android how to cancel event with back key without saving data

Tags: android, keydown, onpause

I am trying to use handle database with insert, update, and delete such as notepad.
I have problem with back key because when I press the back key, I don't want to save any data. In normal case which presses the confirm button, it will be saved into sqlite and will be displayed on listview.
How can I make cancel event through back key or more button event?
I am trying to use onBackPressed, onPause, and onResume.
When I press the back key in edit page, onPause() is calling, but I do not want to use 
saveState() when I pressed back key. How can I make it?
Could you give me some feedback?
Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onPause();
    saveState();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onResume();
    Resume_populateFields();
}

@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      super.onBackPressed();
      finish();    
}    

private void saveState() {
    String name = (String) nameEdit.getText().toString();
    String category = (String) categoryEdit.getText().toString();
    String expired_date = (String) expired_Date_Btn.getText().toString();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable())
            .getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream imageByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imageByteStream);

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.insertItem(category, name, expired_date,
                imageByteStream);

        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateItem(mRowId, category, name, expired_date,
                imageByteStream);
    }
}

    private void Resume_populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor data = mDbHelper.fetchItem(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(data);
        // load information from sqlite
        nameEdit.setText(data.getString(data
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(FridgeDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        categoryEdit.setText(data.getString(data
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(FridgeDbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY)));
        expired_Date_Btn.setText(data.getString(data
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(FridgeDbAdapter.KEY_EXPIRED_DATE)));

    } else {
        // call display date when list is clicked
        expired_Date_Btn.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mDay)
                .append("/")
                // month is 0 based. Then add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mYear).append(" "));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a boolean flag isOnBackeyPressed; Than:

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { 
    Toast.makeText(this, "onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      super.onBackPressed();
      isOnBackeyPressed = true;
      finish();    
}    


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onPause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onPause();
    if (!isOnBackKeyPressed)
       saveState();

}
```

If your lifecycle is different, just adopt the idea.

Comment: Damn it, I was half way through writing that

Comment: Thank you for your replying!! it is simple, and it works properly.